# Decrypting XML file on SD card Android

Tags: android, file, encryption, android-sdcard

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt my app's xml files stored on the sd card [using this code](http://pocket-for-android.1047292.n5.nabble.com/Encryption-method-and-reading-the-Dropbox-backup-td4344194.html#a4454327). While encryption works fine, it's the decryption part where I am stuck.

**Encryption code:**

```
private void writeToFile(final String xmlString, final String exportFileName) throws IOException {
  File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), BData.DATASUBDIRECTORY);
  if (!dir.exists()) {
     dir.mkdirs();
  }
  File file = new File(dir, exportFileName);
  file.createNewFile();

  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
  try {
      String fileData = AdvancedCrypto.encrypt("myPassword", "mySalt"), xmlString.toString());
      bos.write(fileData.getBytes());
  }  catch (Exception e){
  } finally {
      if (bos != null) {
          bos.flush();
          bos.close();
      }
  }

}
```

**Decryption code:**

```
   public void getDataFromXML(Context context, String fileName){
       try
       {
           XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
           factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
           XmlPullParser _xml = factory.newPullParser();

            // get a reference to the file.
           File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + fileName);

            // create an input stream to be read by the stream reader.
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

           BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

           int size = (int) file.length();
           byte[] contents = new byte[size];
           //byte[] data = buf.read(contents);

           String fileData = AdvancedCrypto.decrypt("myPassword", "mySalt"), contents.toString());
           buf.read(fileData.getBytes());

            // set the input for the parser using an InputStreamReader
           _xml.setInput(buf, HTTP.UTF_8);

           buf.close();

           int eventType = _xml.getEventType();
           boolean done = false;       

           //..rest of the code
           }
    }
```

It's throwing this error:

```
07-07 21:44:27.755: W/System.err(5608): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; regionStart=0; regionLength=32
07-07 21:44:27.755: W/System.err(5608):     at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
07-07 21:44:27.755: W/System.err(5608):     at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
```

at this line in the decrypt method:

```
String ivHex = encrypted.substring(0, IV_LENGTH * 2);
```

Am I reading the file correctly to decrypt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays do not override the toString() method in Java. Invoking toString() on a byte array will probably not produce what you are after.

The `AdvancedCrypto.decrypt()` method expects the ciphertext as a string. The corresponding `encrypt` method seems to hex encode the output bytes. The simplest fix to your code would be to change `contents.toString()` to `new String(contents)`. (Note that it's bad practice to rely on the platform default encoding – you should explicitly specify UTF-8 when translating between strings and bytes in either direction.)

However, the simplest fix is not always the best one. Copy-pasting random cryptographic code from the internet is particularly questionable. There's absolutely no reason to hex encode the ciphertext if you're storing it in a file, but this AdvancedCrypto class does it anyway. Using the class this way also involves a lot unnecessary copying of bytes, which will quickly be a performance issue if your data grows beyond a few hundred kilobytes.

Also, remember that the [data is only as secure as the key](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx). If you hardcode the key in your application, then anyone who has access to the application can decrypt the data.

Comment: I have linked the code in the quesiton: http://pocket-for-android.1047292.n5.nabble.com/Encryption-method-and-reading-the-Dropbox-backup-td4344194.html#a4454327